# Is it possible to use Template literal for Component name in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, string-literals

it may be weird, but I want to dynamically route in ReactJs. So, I tried using Template literal for generating the Component name, but its not working. Any idea how its done? or is it not allowed?

```
<Routes>
{
    Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key,index)=>{
    <Route path={`/${pageNav[key]}`} exact element={<`$(pageNav[key])`/>} ></Route>)
}
<Route path={'/home'}  exact element={<HomePage/>} ></Route>
</Routes>
```

**update: including the whole file**

```
import './Navbar.css'
import {Route, Routes, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import ElectronicsPage from '../SubPages/ElectronicsPage/ElectronicsPage'
import FashionPage from '../SubPages/FashionPage/FashionPage'
import BestPage from '../SubPages/BestPage/BestPage'
import FurnituresPage from '../SubPages/FurnituresPage/FurnituresPage'
import GamingPage from '../SubPages/GamingPage/GamingPage'
import GroceriesPage from '../SubPages/GroceriesPage/GroceriesPage'
import HomeAppliancesPage from '../SubPages/HomeAppliancesPage/HomeAppliancesPage'
import Mainpage from '../Homepage/MainPage'
import HomePage from '../Homepage/Homepage'


const Navbar=()=>{


    let Nav_items={"Best Sellers":["Redmi Note 7 Pro", "Mac Pro 2","LG TV 5", "Airtel Data Card"],
                "Electronics":["Mobiles","Laptops","Accessories","Smart Devices"],
                "Fashion":["Men's Casual wear","Women's Casual wear","Men's Formal wear", "Children's wear","Accessories"],
                "Gaming":["Gaming Laptops","Build PCs","Gaming Mobiles","Controllers","Games"],
                "Home Appliances":["TVs","Washing Machines","Refrigerators","Ovens","Air Conditioners","Water Purifiers"],
                "Furnitures":["Tables and Desks","Sofas and Chairs","Wardrobes","Beds and Mattresses","Chimneys and Kitchen set"],
                "Groceries":["Vegetables","Masala items","Instant foods","Cosmetics","Hygiene Products"]
            }
        
    const pageNav={"Best Sellers":"BestPage","Electronics":"ElectronicsPage","Fashion":"FashionPage","Gaming":"GamingPage",
                "Home Appliances":"HomeAppliancesPage","Furnitures":"FurnituresPage","Groceries":"GroceriesPage"}

    
    
    return(
        <div>
        <div data-TestId="nav" className="navbar">
            <Link to={'/home'}><img className="option" src={"./option-button.png"} alt="option-button"/></Link>
            {
                Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key,index)=>
                <div className="nav-button">
                    <Link to={`/${pageNav[key]}`}><button>{key}</button></Link>
                    
                <div className="dropdown">
                    {
                    Nav_items[key].map((k,index)=><div className="dropdown">
                    <button>{k}</button></div>)
                    }
                </div>
                </div>
                )
            }
            </div><div style={{"display":"block"}}>
            <Routes>
            <Route path={'/home'}  exact element={<HomePage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/BestPage'}  exact element={<BestPage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/ElectronicsPage'}  exact element={<ElectronicsPage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/FashionPage'}  exact element={<FashionPage/>}></Route>
            <Route path={'/GamingPage'}  exact element={<GamingPage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/HomeAppliancesPage'}  exact element={<HomeAppliancesPage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/FurnituresPage'}  exact element={<FurnituresPage/>} ></Route>
            <Route path={'/GroceriesPage'}  exact element={<GroceriesPage/>} ></Route>
            </Routes>
        </div></div>
    
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you must compute the component ***before*** rendering the JSX.

[Choosing the Type at runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
<Routes>
  {Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key) => {
    const Component = pageNav[key];
    return <Route path={`/${Component}`} element={<Component />} />
  )}
  <Route path={'/home'} element={<HomePage/>} />
</Routes>
```

This seems to assume that the route path and component to be rendered are named the same, which may not always be ideal or practical.

I suggest some structure more like:

```
const Nav_items = [
  {
    path: ".....",
    Component: MyComponent,
  },
  ...
];
```

Explicitly specify a path and component for each entry:

```
<Routes>
  {Nav_items.map(({ path, Component }) => (
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
  ))}
  <Route path={'/home'} element={<HomePage/>} />
</Routes>
```

### Update

Given:

```
let Nav_items = {
  "Best Sellers": ["Redmi Note 7 Pro", "Mac Pro 2","LG TV 5", "Airtel Data Card"],
  "Electronics": ["Mobiles", "Laptops", "Accessories", "Smart Devices"],
  "Fashion": ["Men's Casual wear", "Women's Casual wear", "Men's Formal wear", "Children's wear", "Accessories"],
  "Gaming": ["Gaming Laptops", "Build PCs", "Gaming Mobiles", "Controllers", "Games"],
  "Home Appliances": ["TVs", "Washing Machines", "Refrigerators", "Ovens", "Air Conditioners", "Water Purifiers"],
  "Furnitures": ["Tables and Desks", "Sofas and Chairs", "Wardrobes", "Beds and Mattresses", "Chimneys and Kitchen set"],
  "Groceries": ["Vegetables", "Masala items", "Instant foods", "Cosmetics", "Hygiene Products"]
}
```

None of the `Nav_items` object keys are the names of any React components you imported:

```
import ElectronicsPage from '../SubPages/ElectronicsPage/ElectronicsPage';
import FashionPage from '../SubPages/FashionPage/FashionPage';
import BestPage from '../SubPages/BestPage/BestPage';
import FurnituresPage from '../SubPages/FurnituresPage/FurnituresPage';
import GamingPage from '../SubPages/GamingPage/GamingPage';
import GroceriesPage from '../SubPages/GroceriesPage/GroceriesPage';
import HomeAppliancesPage from '../SubPages/HomeAppliancesPage/HomeAppliancesPage';
import Mainpage from '../Homepage/MainPage';
import HomePage from '../Homepage/Homepage';
```

***BUT*** `pageNav` appears to have the mapping of the page/link to the component name

```
const pageNav = {
  "Best Sellers": "BestPage",
  "Electronics": "ElectronicsPage",
  "Fashion": "FashionPage",
  "Gaming": "GamingPage",
  "Home Appliances": "HomeAppliancesPage",
  "Furnitures": "FurnituresPage",
  "Groceries": "GroceriesPage"
}
```

You are trying to map `Nav_items` object keys to a value from `pageNave`, but these values are Strings, not React components.

```
{Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key) => {
  const Component = pageNav[key]; // <-- String values!!!
  return <Route path={`/${Component}`} element={<Component />} />
)}
```

To Resolve, fix the mapping in `pageNav` so the values ***are*** the imported React components.

```
const pageNav = {
  "Best Sellers": BestPage,
  "Electronics": ElectronicsPage,
  "Fashion": FashionPage,
  "Gaming": GamingPage,
  "Home Appliances": HomeAppliancesPage,
  "Furnitures": FurnituresPage,
  "Groceries": GroceriesPage
}
```

Now `const Component = pageNav[key];` should actually refer to a React Component and render fine, but since it's no longer a string, won't work for the route `path`. You still need a string. I suggest using the `key`. You may have issues with whitespace, so you may want to strip that out.

```
{Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key) => {
  const Component = pageNav[key];
  return <Route path={`/${key.replace(/\W/g, '')}`} element={<Component />} />
)}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping out. I was using the same map function to create <Link> elements too. Turns out, React works it out up to some point. Compiles without warning, but Pages are not routed, in console, I could see the "No routes matched location "/component_link" ". component_link term is the correct name for every component. Even though, I was using the same map function in both places, this error occurs, I just moved on to manual typing of Routes, for now.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SureshKumar I sure you can get this working as you like. Can you update your question to include and example `Nav_items` that isn't working for mapping the paths and components for routes? From there we should be able to reproduce on our own to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I have edited the question with the current working Routing (manual typing) which I tried to replace by the map function. Kindly take a look at it.

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese, From your answer, I understand, that path needs to be string and the the element should be a component, So, I should map Component names in the page_nav[key], and then stringify the name of the component for path. But that didn't work. So, I even tried, having a copy(page_nav2) which maps the strings to Component names as you suggested and tried the 1st for path and 2nd for Component. That also didn't work. In both cases, what I found was, 'having mapped the Component in the object, does not return the Component, instead, an arrow function is returned' which cant be rendered

Comment: @SureshKumar I don't quite follow; paths are strings, `element` is a React component as JSX. It's unclear what isn't working. Can you clarify what you mean "an arrow function is returned?

Comment: @SureshKumar The keys in both `Nav_items` and `pageNav` are strings though. Where are you getting they become functions? `Object.keys(Nav_items)` -> `["Best Sellers", "Electronics", ..., "Groceries"]`. I'll test this out in a codesandbox.

Comment: I found the solution, I am using the Component name in page_nav, and to get the path, I am using the method, Component.name   const pageNav={"Best Sellers":BestPage,"Electronics":ElectronicsPage,"Fashion":FashionPage,"Gaming":GamingPage,
                "Home Appliances":HomeAppliancesPage,"Furnitures":FurnituresPage,"Groceries":GroceriesPage}              {Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key) => {
                const Component = pageNav[key];
                console.log(Component.name)
                return( <Route path={`/${pageNav[key].name}`} element={<Component/>} />)})}

Comment: @SureshKumar Yeah, I copied the code into a CSB and sure enough I do see where the `path` is using some stringified version of a function for some reason, even though a console log of the `key` a line above logs the string value as expected. Seems very odd.

Comment: @SureshKumar Oh, it was the links you were generating, they were using `pathName[key]` and used the stringified React function as the link... you want to render link paths the same as the routes being rendered, i.e. `<Link to={\`/${key.replace(/\W/g, '')}\`}><button>{key}</button></Link>`. Sorry for not explicitly calling that out that you would possibly need to generate the links to match the routes. https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-jepsen-stv86?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese, Sorry if my question was not clear, But solution could not be found without your help, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can not use template literal string for components.

But you can use this approach for your purpose

```
<Routes>
{
  Object.keys(Nav_items).map((key,index) => {
    const Component = pageNav[key];
    return (
      <Route path={`/${pageNav[key]}`} exact element={<Component />} />
    )
  })
  <Route path={'/home'}  exact element={<HomePage/>} ></Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping out. I was using the same map function to create <Link> elements too. Turns out, React works it out up to some point. Compiles without warning, but Pages are not routed, in console, I could see the "No routes matched location "/component_link" ". component_link term is the correct name for every component. Even though, I was using the same map function in both places, this error occurs, I just moved on to manual typing of Routes, for now.  Thanks again.